# Django modeltranslation adds ALL available languages to our table - not only the ones we want - why?

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

Today we evaluated django-modeltranslation for our project - and it looks good. There's only one caveat: on our table all available python languages are added - not only the ones we need.

In the documentation it says: "Warning - Modeltranslation does not enforce the LANGUAGES setting to be defined in your project. When it isn’t present (and neither is MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES), it defaults to Django’s global LANGUAGES setting instead, and that are quite a few languages!"

Fair enough - but we have languages defined in settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ('en', 'de')
MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_PREPOPULATE_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_FALLBACK_LANGUAGES = ('en', 'de')
MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_FILES = (
    'salesUnit.translation',
)
```

Any ideas why columns for all languages are generated on our table?